# Issue with ng-model on select tag in firefox angular js

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I am using Angular Js v1.6.1. I used following code to generate select list

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedLocation">
     <option ng-repeat="item in locations" value="{{item}}">
          {{item}}
     </option>
</select>
```

In Google chrome I am getting results as excepted as shown in image below.
[image]

But in firefox, I got the following results

[image]

There is blank after select location in firefox. How to resolve this issue?

Location Object:

[image]

Bootstrap Version: 3.3.7
FireFox version: 51.0.1 (32-bit)

Comment: Can you post `locations` object as well and tell the bootstrap and firefox version

Comment: @nivas I have edited the post and added the details you asked for.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you initialize the `selectedLocation` scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended way to use ng-repeat in options if you want to generate options dynamically.

Try [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead.

Can you check the below and let me know if the problem still persist ?.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', []);
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.locations = ['Farm1', 'Farm2', 'All'];
    }
  ]);

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Select Item</div>

  <select class="form-control" ng-init="selectedLocation= locations[0]" ng-model="selectedLocation" ng-options="item as item for item in locations" style="width:150px">
  </select>
  <div>Selected item: {{selectedLocation}}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still no success. Here is the screen shot http://i.imgur.com/abBaGuI.png

Comment: @NewStark I think it is the issue with CSS. Can you try printing the selected value in the same template itself?

Comment: What do you mean by same template and what selected value. selected value by select tag?

Comment: I have **`<div>Selected item: {{selectedLocation}}</div>`** in my code which will show the select tag value when user selects

Comment: I tried printing `selectedLocation` inside division and it displays value correctly. It works fine with google chrome.

Comment: @NewStark I guess the issue is with CSS  and I've added `style="width:150px"` just for debugging purpose. Can you check my answer now ?

Comment: It works by adding `style="width:150px"` but it creates further problems. I have multiple select tags and each of them require different width. It also creates problem when I visits website in phone.

Comment: @NewStark I added width to check for styling issues. It worked means the issue is with styling not with `angular`. so check the styles that are applying for select tag and do the changes neccessarily

Comment: I found the issue.width of `form-control` class. when I remove width from `form-control` it works. but I don't think that is a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used same version but I don't have any problem . [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/07Sextu8h8LmPuTHN3Ii?p=preview) here and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSax8.png) here

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.locations = ['Farm1', 'Farm2', 'All'];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>Select Item</div>
    
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedLocation">
     <option ng-repeat="item in locations" value="{{item}}">
          {{item}}
     </option>
    </select>
    
    <div>Selected item: {{selectedLocation}}</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still not resolved. Here is the screenshot of html generated by my code and html generated by your plunkr http://i.imgur.com/rgxfKwL.png

Comment: It's really hard to solve browser specific errors. Try changing the array to something else and make sure you don't have `id` and `name` attribute defined with same `ng-model` i.e. `selectedLocation` anywhere in your page.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It was problem with the style not with angular js. I changed the width to auto and it displays correctly in both browsers.

Comment: Glad you find the solution